# How to allocate partition? (while Installing Dualboot Ubuntu & existing Win7)

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I have been using the existing Win7 for a long time and now want to install Ubuntu dualboot.

I have two drives C:(35.9gb free out of 111gb)  & D: (111gb free out of 165gb)

I tried Ubuntu and after clicking install it asks me about the partition.
It says my hard drive has 120gb, and on the slider the suggested partition reads 111gb on the left and 60gb on the right.

How should I allocate the partition? I don't know why the numbers don't sum up ..

I'm a complete noob at things like this so I'd be very grateful if anyone can explain and help me with the partition! Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: and now my main question is that if I "install alongside Windows7" will it automatically partition for me? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why the numbers don't sum up

The numbers do seem to add up; Ubuntu is suggesting that you install Ubuntu on the disk with the most free space (the one windows calls D:). It's now:

```
[ 111 gb free | 60 gb used ] (All Windows)
```

Ubuntu is suggesting:

```
[ 100 gb Ubuntu | 60 gb Windows ]
```

However, I'd like to warn you that moving data *within partitions* (as is the case here) is *dangerous*. You really should backup all your data on D: before doing this, unless you don't care about losing it. When you've done that, you can setup the partitions however you like. I'd recommend atleast 30 Gb for Ubuntu to be safe, but depending on what OS you expect to use the most, you might want to use more or less. You could even use all of D: for Ubuntu, and the other disk only for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! So if I want to use 40Gb on D: for ubuntu, how should I do that?

Comment: You can probably just move the slider in the installation program so that the "Ubuntu part" says 40 Gb and the other part is using the rest. As I've said: it's dangerous and you really should backup all the data on the Windows part of the drive.

Comment: How can I make it less dangerous? Should I partition 40Gb as sth new on win7 first?

Comment: btw I read somewhere that the "install alongside windows" option of Ubuntu 12.04 will help me partition the free space into a new drive... is that true?

Comment: Yes, the "install alongside windows" will help you do exactly that. It's dangerous because if you're resizing partitions and something goes wrong, the partitions can become unreadable. You won't destroy anything, but you might lose data. Because of this, I highly recommend you do backups so that it doesn't matter IF you lose data.

Comment: This is why I recommended that you can use C: for Windows (and not touch it with Ubuntu) and clean out D: completely and use that for Ubuntu only, to stay safe :)